# Unable Train on Tpu Google Colab InternalError: 9 root error(s) found

Tags: data-science, google-colaboratory

```
BATCH SIZE = 64
HEIGHT ,WIDTH = 124,124

Train_data set   = 14906 6 classes.
Validation_datat =  3726 6 classes.

with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  model = complile_model(model,lr=0.0001)
  callbacks = create_callbacks()
epochs = 5
steps_per_epoch  = 14906//BATCH_SIZE
validation_steps = 3726//BATCH_SIZE

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset, 
                    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

I am trying to train it on TPU provided by google collab but unable to do so kindly help me regarding this. Have attached the screen-shot

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since ImageDataGenerator also uses PyFunction under the hood, it is incompatible with TPUs. Instead, you have to use the tf.data API to load images. This tutorial explains how to do it.

Comment: Which tutorial? I really thought this only ImageDatagenrerator is causing the problem!

Comment: Dataset.from_generator is expected to not work with TPUs as it uses py_function underneath which is incompatible with Cloud TPU 2VM setup. If you would like to read from large datasets, maybe try to materialize it on disk and use TFRecordDataest instead.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Dataset must `repeat()`:

```py
def get_dataset(filenames, batch_size):
    dataset = (
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
        .map(parse_tfrecord_fn, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .map(prepare_sample, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .repeat()
        .shuffle(batch_size * 10)
        .batch(batch_size)
        .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )
    return dataset
```